# React components does not get effected by css

Tags: css, reactjs

I create two components in React, and I want to display them both on the App component.
While they do show on the page, I can't use CSS to give each of them flex for example.
I want each component to take half of the screen size, this is what I have:

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TopJourney id="Top-journey-section" />
      <JourneysSection id="Journeys-section" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#Top-journey-section {
  flex: 1;
}

#Journeys-section {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: greenyellow; // I added this just to be sure that the css does not work.
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `id` as a prop to your component, but you are not using it.

Wrong:

```
 <TopJourney id="Top-journey-section" />
```

Good:

```
function TopJourney({id}) {
 <div id={id}>your component stuff</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the flex still does not working, as far as I know, flex 1 tells the div to take as much space as possible, am I right? because, it does take the 100% of the width, but nothing about the height.

Comment: Not sure, I need more code if you have other issues. You can mark this one as solved and or create some example or codepen so I can debug futher.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors `id` or `className` only works on native HTML elements, not on Components, try adding styles on HTML dom elements instead. For components, these are just regular props that you can use within the component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusion of css flexbox column and row. it should be row and change the **id** into className, then.... change the css file as well below.

```html
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TopJourney className="Top-journey-section" />
      <JourneysSection className="Journeys-section" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS file should be looks like this

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
}

.Top-journey-section {
  width:50%;
}

.Journeys-section {
  width:50%;
  background-color: greenyellow; // I added this just to be sure that the css does not work.
}
```